BIOS drive order is inverse of Windows'
After installing a 2nd SSD on my laptop, I noticed this complete nonsense:
Here's the BIOS:

Here's Windows disk management:

What should I do?
Swap them to fix order in Windows? Thing is, doing so will swap BIOS' order...
Or just leave things like they are?

Why do you care about the order? If everything is working don’t change anything. Best not touch anything when it doesn’t change anything, only real way you could “fix” the situation, would be to format and reinstall Windows entirely. Really won’t change the situation since the order doesn’t change anything

Well, it just feels weird to see them recognized in a different order. But yes, it doesn't really matter as long as it works.

"I noticed this complete nonsense" - Is this a question or a rant?

@marcelm It is quite weird to say the least, I've never encountered such issue until now.

Surprised to see proportional fonts in a BIOS. I would typically associate that with EFI.

It really doesn't matter.
Modern operating systems generally do not use the BIOS for disks; that was something Windows 98 did, and then generally as last resort, but Windows 10 talks directly to the disk controller without any involvement from the system firmware.
The order might be different because both of your disks are NVMe, meaning that they're independent devices on the PCI bus – unlike e.g. SATA, where the controller would just have ports numbered 1-6 or so, PCIe device numbering can be a mess and I wouldn't be surprised if M.2 slot #2 on your laptop happened to have a lower PCIe bus:slot number than M.2 slot #1, for example (and the firmware settings screen knew that but the OS had no reason to care). Or it might be that the Samsung SSD initialized slightly faster and therefore got "disk #0" in Windows.

Yes, best to not change anything, I noticed Windows Boot Manager entry appearing in boot order, better just rely on it; maybe I'll just have to set boot drive once after reinstalling and then it'll pick it up.

That's the whole idea. UEFI-style firmware does not use "boot drives" generally – it uses manually defined boot entries that specify a partition UUID and a file path. Installing Windows (or running bcdboot.exe) will create a boot entry for the new system partition.

That's a good thing, going to try reinstall, thanks for your help!

@aybe There is no need to reinstall.

@Sneftel I am but for another reason: years of fiddling, it's having a hard time now :)
